# Recover a closed question?

Tags: support, closing-questions, votes

I have asked to close a question, but now it cannot be found anymore. It is not even on the list of my questions. Is there a way to recover it? The link is: [Generating likely populations given a subsample and control totals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23529)

Comment: Of course -- in fact you should be able to see it. If it is somewhat not working, I can e-mail it to you, post here or even undelete on the site.

Comment: No, I'm getting a "page not found" error. Could you please undelete it (with the comment(s)) but keep the "closed" state?

Comment: mbq is right: the question is still there.  As I was the one who deleted it (at your request), I have undeleted it so you don't have to wait any longer to get access to it.  (It still would be good to find out why you can't see the deleted question.)  You should be able to delete it or close it yourself, but the best action simply is to edit it as you see fit.

Comment: Now I see the question again. Thank you.

Comment: @whuber People below 10k rep can't see deleted questions, including their own. That's basically by design.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Anna.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness sake: Your question was restored (as **whuber** mentioned above) and the privilege for seeing deleted questions is [available as tool for 10k users](https://stats.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools).